# MySQL: INSERT or UPDATE if exists, but not based on key column

Tags: mysql, sql

What I have is a table of completed training. Each user has a username. Each user may completed numerous courses.

The table has the following headers:

```
+-------------------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| recordnumber (KEY - AI) | username |  type   | course  | status  | started | completed |
+-------------------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| int                     | varchar  | varchar | varchar | varchar | date    | date      |
+-------------------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

And I have a PHP script set up to populate the db from a CSV upload.

What I'm trying to achieve is for it to add new rows, and to update existing ones.

The problem is that recordnumber (they key, unique field) is not constant. So instead of doing a "ON DUPLICATE KEY" query, I want to do it based on whether username and course already exist as a row.

Basically to say "If this username already has this course, update the other fields. If the username does not have this course, add this as a new row".

The query that I have at the moment (which works based on key) is:

```
INSERT into table(recordnumber, username,type,course,status,started,completed) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]')

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username='$data[1]',type='$data[2]',course='$data[3]',status='$data[4]',started='$data[5]',completed='$data[6]'
```

Any thoughts on how I could amend the query to get it to check based on username and course instead of duplicate key?

Thank you. :-)

Comment: Create your own "ON DUPLICATE KEY" type function. You could utilize IF THEN statements to this effect. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Comment: create a key on the username column and then use on duplicate key

Comment: There are many suggestions and answers that suggest performing the check on your own - please don't, none of these examples are safe from concurrency - that means you can (and most likely will) end up with duplicate records. What you should do is continue using your `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` approach, but your key would be `UNIQUE(username, course)` instead of just username.

Comment: @mjh That's really good advice. Thank you. I've fixed it up using this method and it works beautifully. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL 'UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY' without a unique column?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3180913/90527)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most correct way would be to create a unique index on username - course columns and use on duplicate key update.

Obviously, you can issue a select before the insert checking for existing record with same user name and course and issue an insert or an update as appropriate.

Comment: Good shout. This has fixed the issue. :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

create a key on the username and course column and then use on duplicate key

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    course varchar(255),
    num_entries INT DEFAULT 0,
    UNIQUE KEY (username, course)
);

insert into test (username, course) values
('billybob', 'math'),
('billy', 'math'),
('billybob', 'math'),
('bob', 'math')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num_entries = num_entries + 1;
```

this is a simple example, but you should understand what to do from here

[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2d24/1)

so putting this to work on your table

```
ALTER TABLE `courses` -- assuming the table is named courses
    ADD CONSTRAINT `UK_COURSE_USERNAME` UNIQUE (username, course);
```

then your insert should just be the same as what you have

Answer (score 1):

Example query in reference to my comment above.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT id FROM Table WHERE username = '$data[1]' AND course <> '$data[3]')
(
UPDATE username='$data[1]',type='$data[2]',course='$data[3]',status='$data[4]',started='$data[5]',completed='$data[6]'
)
(
INSERT into table(recordnumber, username,type,course,status,started,completed) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]')
)
```

Comment: I got `IF statement is not valid in this position`. Any solutions?

Comment: @LushaLi you need to wrap it into a procedure https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-procedure#:~:text=MySQL%20Stored%20Procedure,parameter%20lists%2C%20and%20SQL%20statements.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if you added unique constraint for username and course value pair like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD CONSTRAINT `UK_table_username_course` UNIQUE (username, course);
```