# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not working as expected

Tags: mysql, composite-key, on-duplicate-key

I have a table looking something like this

| id (Primary Key, Auto increment) | user_type | name | some_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Type 1 | Name 1 | Some value 1 |
| 2 | Type 2 | Name 2 | Some value 2 |

I want to utilise `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` by having the `user_type` and `name` as a composite index.
I have followed these two answers:
[MySQL: INSERT or UPDATE if exists, but not based on key column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215734/mysql-insert-or-update-if-exists-but-not-based-on-key-column)
[MySQL 'UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY' without a unique column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180913/mysql-update-on-duplicate-key-without-a-unique-column)

And I have created a composite index

```
CREATE INDEX test_table_composite ON test_table (user_type, name)
```

And then I've tried invoking an insert like this

```
INSERT INTO test_table (user_type, name, some_column)
VALUES ("Type 1", "Name 1", "Some value 1")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
some_column = VALUES(some_column);
```

Followed by another one

```
INSERT INTO test_table (user_type, name, some_column)
VALUES ("Type 1", "Name 1", "Some other value")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
some_column = VALUES(some_column);
```

However this results in two inserts instead of an insert and an update. I am assuming that it is using the primary key instead of the index to determine whether it's a duplicate or not. What am I doing wrong and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: Created index is NOT unique.

Comment: To be more clear: The row you insert counts as a duplicate only if it conflicts with a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY in the table. If you create an index as you show, that's a non-unique index, which permits duplicates, so there is no reason for it to trigger the ON DUPLICATE KEY part of your statement. It is behaving as intended.